# Printing the path in dijstra's algorithm

Tags: c, dijkstra, shortest-path

i was given an implementation of dijstras algorithm by my cs professor, and he asked us to modify it to print the path from the source node "src" (see code) to each node, along with the distance (which it already does).  I have looked at this for about a week now, and tried several things.  i cannot figure it out for the life of me... any help would be appreciated.  The graph is represented by an adjecency matrix, and there is a global containing its size:

```
int n; //Global matrix's size
int minDistance(int dist[], bool sptSet[]){
    // Initialize min value
    int min = INT_MAX, min_index;
    int i = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (sptSet[i] == false && dist[i] <= min)
            min = dist[i], min_index = i; 
   return min_index;
}

int printSolution(int dist[]){
   printf("Vertex   Distance from Source\n");
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      printf("%d \t\t %d\n", i, dist[i]);
}

void dijkstra(int ** graph, int src){
    //correting zeros (won't work with negative values)
    correctZeros(graph);
    int dist[n]; 
    bool sptSet[n];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        dist[i] = INT_MAX, sptSet[i] = false;
    dist[src] = 0;

    // Find shortest path for all vertices
    int count;
    for (count = 0; count < n; count++){
        int u = minDistance(dist, sptSet);
        sptSet[u] = true;
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
            printf("%d", u);
            if (!sptSet[j] && graph[u][j] && dist[u] != INT_MAX && dist[u]+graph[u][j] < dist[j]){
                dist[j] = dist[u] + graph[u][j];

            }
        }
    }
    printSolution(dist);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to store for each node what is its next hop for the shortest path. This information will be updated whenever you're updating the distance of the shortest path of a node.

Answer (score 0):

Use Another Array to store the previous node when you do your Relax calculation.

```
node[src] = src; //init source node
if (!sptSet[j] && graph[u][j] && dist[u] != INT_MAX && dist[u]+graph[u][j] < dist[j]){
            dist[j] = dist[u] + graph[u][j];
            node[j] = u; //store previous node step
        }
```

Use a loop to print all nodes until node[x] = x (the source node)

```
printPath(int node[], int i, int src)
{

    int currentNode = i;
    printf(currentNode); 
    while(currentNode!=src)
    {
         printf(node[currentNode]);
         currentNode = node[currentNode];
    }
}
```

I am not very familiar with C Language, so maybe there are some C grammar errors. Thanks.